# I destroyed the bootanimation of my phone and now it's stuck in the boot screen (black screen)

Tags: rooting, boot

So I rooted my phone (Cherry mobile flare 2) and tried to messed up with the boot animation file :3, I changed the bootanimation.zip and changed the pictures in attempt to manually change the boot animation. But after that it has been stuck in the boot animation logo because of what I did. >-< I already tried to hard reset it but it does not work. I have the stock formware here but it requires teamwin recovery but the problem is i don't know how to install the teamwin recovery on my phone because the USB Debugging is not open. Thank you!

Comment: Download the firmware online and then install it via SP flash tool.

Comment: https://firmwarefile.com/cherry-mobile-flare-2-0

Comment: It requires PC and Mediatek USB Drivers @user276216.

Comment: Never edit ROM from inside. That way, if you get stuck, you'll at least have previous way to restore the ROM.